# Redirecting non logged-in users from .html pages?

Tags: php, html

I am doing some patchwork on an old and outdated site. It's based on PHP but there is no framework, and a bunch of pages are static (.html).

I created a simple login system for the site, but now the client wants the system to work for the static pages as well - basically, a member who isn't logged in should be redirected from them.

However, since there is no session, no include and no PHP code in general, I'm unsure as to how to proceed. My only idea is to send an AJAX request before the page loads to check if there's a session, and do a client-side redirect if not, but that seems a bit sketchy.

The client doesn't want to use an HTTP authentication popup, but rather the new PHP login system.

Has someone been in this situation? Any solutions that don't involve me going into every file, renaming them to .php and updating all the links on the site to reflect that would be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem I think is really **AJAX**

But if HTML pages in apache or php server, you can create a .htaccess to read if page is .html and pass to *page_check.php* and script check if logged and redirect or simple read the .html file and put content on the screen.

#### htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ check_page.php?page=$1 [L, QSA]
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];

$file = getcwd() . $page;
// check if logged and redirect
...

// if not redirected then 
if(file_exists($page)){
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    echo $content;
} else {
    // redirect if file no exists
    header('Location: 404.php');
}

?>
```

I hope that gives you a direction.